# Current object information inside OSL custom shader

Tags: osl

I'd like to build a custom OSL Emission shader which behaves as follows:

1) Input parameters:

- float **Initial** = 0   // minimum emission intensity
- float **Final** = 1     // maximum emission intensity

2) Output:

- output closure color Emission = 0

3) Applied to a plane with Origin at the left side edge it produces a light emission varying (linearly or by whatever else rule) from:

- **Initial** at left side edge

  to:
- **Final** at right side edge

I've no problems applying the **Initial** rule but can't figure out how to apply the **Final**.

**Initial** emission is to be assigned at X=0 (in Object coordinates) but what about **Final** emission?

If I knew information about the size of the current object I could derive the rule to make the emission assume the **Final** value at the right edge.

Is there a way to get such information inside an OSL script?

Thank you.

Comment: I don't think you can get that large of a view, you are [limited to what is needed](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/nodes/osl.html#attributes) for the point being sampled. You can get the UV coordinates, if the plane is unwrapped to fill the uv layout then you get a value from 0-1 to match the sides.

Comment: Thank you, at the simple cost of adding UV mapping, this provide a relative reference to the points of the plane independent from the size of the actual object.